# Return record with max column value using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

Trying to get record with max ***datetime*** value for `ReceivedDateTime` column, however data set should be pre-filtered by some `Id` column (not unique). Solved this way:

```
using (var db = new SystemEntities())
{
    var records = db.Table.Where(p => p.Id == Id);
    var record = records.Where(p => p.ReceivedDateTime == records.Max(r => r.ReceivedDateTime)).FirstOrDefault();
    if(record != null)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there more beautiful, simpler and shorter implementation, notation? Thanks!

Comment: What if there are ties?

Comment: @GertArnold, "ties"?

Comment: Yes, two records, same Id, same date.

Comment: @GertArnold not possible - it is datetime, saves current date time for and id, could not appear simultaneously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simplify like the following using `OrderByDescending`:

```
using (var db = new SystemEntities())
{
    var record = db.Table.Where(p => p.Id == Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.ReceivedDateTime).FirstOrDefault();
    if(record != null){}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Between the time I opened the question and tried out a result, the original answer had been fixed. My apologies for not checking before I posted.

**Update**

Seeing as I cannot comment, I will post an answer on the side.

The above suggested `var record = db.Table.Where(p => p.Id == Id).Max(x => x.ReceivedDateTime).FirstOrDefault()` will not compile because Max will return for you a datetime.

You can do it using OrderByDescending they way you would in an SQL statement

```
// I used an in memory array but it should be the same.
var item = items.Where(x => x.Id == 2).OrderByDescending(x => x.ReceivedDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, at the time I first posted the answer was not yet there. At lease when I opened to write the post. The inline code in my post is what the answer looked like at the time. I wanted to point out what was up but could not. I opened VS to write out the code and then I pasted it back here and posted. Then I discovered that the previous answer had been updated. I can now comment so this will never happen again. Thanks