# Query for parent with one child with a least valued property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following models -

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
}

public class Purchase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Purchase PurchaseWithLeastTotal { get; set; }
}
```

To find a customer with their purchase of least total, I came up with the query -

```cs
var result = dbCtx.Customers
        .Where(p => p.Id == id)
        .Select(p => new CustomerDto
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name,
            PurchaseWithLeastTotal = p.Purchases.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Total == p.Purchases.Min(y => y.Total))
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

which generates the following `SQL` -

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [t].[Id], [t].[CustomerId], [t].[Total]
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) [p].[Id], [p].[CustomerId], [p].[Total]
    FROM [Purchases] AS [p]
    WHERE ([p].[Total] = (
        SELECT MIN([p0].[Total])
        FROM [Purchases] AS [p0]
        WHERE [c].[Id] = [p0].[CustomerId])) AND ([c].[Id] = [p].[CustomerId])
) AS [t]
WHERE [c].[Id] = 1
```

What could be a better (in terms of performance) way to do this query?

Comment: PurchaseWithLeastTotal = p.Purchases,Min(x => y.Total)

Comment: @jdweng `PurchaseWithLeastTota` is of type `Purchase` not `int`.

Comment: It is a instance of a Purchase class  with a ID and Total whch are integers.  How can a class have a min value.  It is a complex object not a number.

Comment: Cant check right now, Would this perform better? `PurchaseWithLeastTotal = p.Purchases.OrderByDescending(x => x.Total).FirstOrDefault()` (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619119)

Comment: @ShayD Thanks. I'll check it. But I think you meant `.OrderBy()`, not `.OrderByDescending()`.

Comment: @atiyar You right, ByDesc would give the max result.